# Automatically create a polygon around other polygons depending on attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I have 1000+ polygons, each has an attribute "Project_Area".

There are maybe 8 different project areas. Is it possible using built-in Tools or Python to create a new shapefile that encompasses each of the 8 project areas?

Its not the hardest task to do manually, but I shall need to do it many times in the next few weeks.

Comment: I think you need Dissolve tool and select Dissolve field "Project_Area"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create what is called a convex hull.

This can be done in ArcGIS using the "[Minimum bounding geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0103000001zt000000)" tool, with the "List" option to use the field values to group the feature together.